# Network Printer Install Script Error

Tags: printing, vbscript, windows-xp, windows-server-2003

I have a VB script that I am using to connect all the computers in a school to a Networked printer on a print server. The code below is the script I am using. The script out puts "Error Line:4 Char:1 Windows cannot open this program because it has been limited by your software restriction policy"

`Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
PrinterPath = "\\018printserver\barrett"
PrinterDriver = "Dell 2330dn Laser Printer"
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrinterPath, PrinterDriver
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\018printserver\barrett"`

The user computers are running windows xp and the server is Windows server 2003 R2. Any ideas on the cause?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if there's a Group Policy enabled to block the actions being taken in your script.

Perhaps check the Event Viewer for more details. There may be a Policy Rule identifier or Guid.